# jqGrid: Problem using editurl to call RESTful method

Tags: c#, jqgrid-asp.net

This is the code I am using to load my jqGrid:

```
 function getTopics() {
     var fid = document.getElementById("SelectFunction").value;
     //alert(fid);
     $.ajax({
         url: "Restful.svc/GetTopics",
         data: { functionID: fid },
         dataType: "json",
         type: "GET",
         contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
         success: function (data, status, xHR) {

             var thegrid = jQuery("#editgrid")[0];

             thegrid.addJSONData(JSON.parse(data.d));
             $("#editgrid").fluidGrid({ example: "#outerContainer", offset: -10 });
         },
         error: function (xHR, status, err) {
             alert("ERROR: " + status + ", " + err);
         }
     });
 }

 function LoadDataIntoGrid() {

     var lastcell;

     jQuery("#editgrid").jqGrid('GridUnload');

         jQuery("#editgrid").jqGrid({
             datatype: getTopics,
             height: '300px',
             colNames: ['TopicID', 'Topic', 'Description', 'Topic Entity', 'Inactive'],
             colModel: [
                    { name: 'TopicID', index: 'TopicID', width: 200, editable: false, editoptions: { readonly: true, size: 10} },
                    { name: 'TopicCode', index: 'TopicCode', width: 100, editable: true, editoptions: { size: 10} },
                    { name: 'TopicDescription', index: 'TopicDescription', width: 200, editable: true, editoptions: { size: 30} },
                    { name: "TopicEntity", index: "TopicEntity", width: 200, editable: true, resizable: true, edittype: "select", editoptions: { value: returnEntityList()} },
                    { name: 'Inactive', index: 'Inactive', width: 60, align: "center", editable: true, edittype: "checkbox", formatter: 'checkbox', formatoptions: { disabled: true} }
                    ],
             rowNum: 30,
             rowList: [10, 20, 30],
             pager: $('#pagernav'),
             sortname: 'Topic',
             viewrecords: true,
             sortorder: "desc",
             caption: "Topics",
             editurl: "Restful.svc/SaveTopic",
             onSelectRow: function (id) {
                 if (id && id !== lastcell) {
                     jQuery('#editgrid').jqGrid('restoreRow', lastcell);
                     jQuery('#editgrid').jqGrid('editRow', id, true);
                     lastcell = id;
                 } 
             }
         }).navGrid('#pagernav', { edit: false, add: true, del: false });

 }
```

Everything loads properly, and clicking on a row makes the fields editable like it should.  When the enter key is pressed to save the edits the event seems to fire properly, and calls the "SaveTopic" method referenced in the editurl property.  At this point I get an error.

If SaveTopic is defined like this:

```
    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "POST", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
    public void SaveTopic( string TopicCode, string TopicDescription, string TopicEntity, string Inactive, string oper, string id)
    {
        //Code Here
    }
```

I get this error from jqGrid: "Error Row: 3 Result: 500:Internal Server Error Status: error"

If SaveTopic is defined like this(Method changed to GET):

```
    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "GET", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
    public void SaveTopic( string TopicCode, string TopicDescription, string TopicEntity, string Inactive, string oper, string id)
    {
        //Code Here
    }
```

I get this error from jqGrid: "Error Row: 3 Result: 405:Method Not Allowed Status: error"

I can't find anyone else having this problem, and according to the similar example I could find I seem to be doing it correctly.  All help is greatly appreciated at this point.

Comment: When SaveTopic is labeled as "POST" in the operation contract I get "500: Internal Server Error".  The method definitions I have tried and the corresponding errors are detailed above.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally managed to to make it work using this work around.  It isn't ideal, but it gets the job done.  Code changes in bold.

```
function getTopics() 
     var fid = document.getElementById("SelectFunction").value;
     //alert(fid);
     $.ajax({
         url: "Restful.svc/GetTopics",
         data: { functionID: fid },
         dataType: "json",
         type: "GET",
         contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
         success: function (data, status, xHR) {

             var thegrid = jQuery("#editgrid")[0];

             thegrid.addJSONData(JSON.parse(data.d));
             $("#editgrid").fluidGrid({ example: "#outerContainer", offset: -10 });
         },
         error: function (xHR, status, err) {
             alert("ERROR: " + status + ", " + err);
         }
     });
 }

 function LoadDataIntoGrid() {

     var lastcell;

     jQuery("#editgrid").jqGrid('GridUnload');

         jQuery("#editgrid").jqGrid({
             datatype: getTopics,
**ajaxGridOptions: { contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8' },**
             height: '300px',
             colNames: ['TopicID', 'Topic', 'Description', 'Topic Entity', 'Inactive'],
             colModel: [
                    { name: 'TopicID', index: 'TopicID', width: 200, editable: false, editoptions: { readonly: true, size: 10} },
                    { name: 'TopicCode', index: 'TopicCode', width: 100, editable: true, editoptions: { size: 10} },
                    { name: 'TopicDescription', index: 'TopicDescription', width: 200, editable: true, editoptions: { size: 30} },
                    { name: "TopicEntity", index: "TopicEntity", width: 200, editable: true, resizable: true, edittype: "select", editoptions: { value: returnEntityList()} },
                    { name: 'Inactive', index: 'Inactive', width: 60, align: "center", editable: true, edittype: "checkbox", formatter: 'checkbox', formatoptions: { disabled: true} }
                    ],
             rowNum: 30,
             rowList: [10, 20, 30],
             pager: $('#pagernav'),
             sortname: 'Topic',
             viewrecords: true,
             sortorder: "desc",
             caption: "Topics",
             editurl: "Restful.svc/SaveTopic",
             onSelectRow: function (id) {
                 if (id && id !== lastcell) {
                     jQuery('#editgrid').jqGrid('restoreRow', lastcell);
                     jQuery('#editgrid').jqGrid('editRow', id, true);
                     lastcell = id;
                 } 
             }
         }).navGrid('#pagernav', { edit: false, add: true, del: false });

 }
        [OperationContract]
        [WebInvoke(Method = "POST", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
        public void SaveTopic() {

            **int FunctionID = Convert.ToInt32(HttpContext.Current.Request.Form["FunctionID"]);
            int TopicID = Convert.ToInt32(HttpContext.Current.Request.Form["TopicID"]);
            string TopicCode = HttpContext.Current.Request.Form["TopicCode"];
            string TopicDescription = HttpContext.Current.Request.Form["TopicDescription"];
            int TopicEntity = Convert.ToInt32(HttpContext.Current.Request.Form["TopicEntity"]);
            string Inactive = HttpContext.Current.Request.Form["Inactive"];
            string oper = HttpContext.Current.Request.Form["oper"];
            string id = HttpContext.Current.Request.Form["id"];**

            //Code here

        }
```

Comment: Bold formatting didn't work.  Only enclosed the changes in ** **.  Look for those to see the modifications.

Answer (score 1):

1. WCF Services only allow HTTP Post requests: Hence they are not RESTFul otherwise they would pass data via the URL in a GET Request.
2. Your method says it accepts individual items ie a lot of strings. This is incorrect, automatic JSon binding isn't smart enough to bind each item separately. Try creating an information agent with the correct properties and receive that or a JSONResult object and parsing the data yourself. If you rely on automatic binding make sure to use the latest version of the .NET frame work either 3.5 SP1 or higher in which automatic JSon to Model binding is allowed.

Sources: Asp.net, Microsoft MVC 3.0 reference guide, msdn, trirand.com, ect.